# Xampp not working with port 8080 in remote desktop IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7, xampp

I am trying to connect xampp server on remote desktop from external http address.
The default port 80 is using by the IIS server and then 
i have changed the xampp server port from 80 to 8080
and trying to access from outside like 
myipaddress:8080 but it is displaying webpage not available message,

After that for testing purpose i have stopped the IIS and running the xampp server on port 80
and then trying to access the php application of xampp using myipaddress:80

now it is working fine,
but i need to run both IIS and XAMPP servers 
i mean IIS on default port 80 and XAMPP on port 8080

How do i achieve this, please give me suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Die hou check that THE port is actualiteit open in tour firewall?

Comment: thanks for your reply,i didnt check it ,but i have stopped the firewall.i will check it now

Comment: i added the port 8080 (added the custome rule ) in firewall inbound.Now it working fine for me thanks you for your valueble reply